# Easy and reliable way to check if user is logged in or not using javascript [ForumMotion]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a forummotion site. I want to show a popup if user is logged in. Is there easy and reliable way to check whether user is logged in or not using JS/jQuery. I have a idea but it is not reliable and i think it cannot be implemented. The idea is:

> Send AJAX request to /profile it will be redirected to index page if
>   user is not logged in otherwise existence of any element which is
>   usually present on /profile page would indicate the user is logged in.

Comment: What are you trying to do if you know the users logged in?  Any client side check can easily be hacked. I.e I could just say I am logged in when I am not.

Comment: @Nix hey man just a popup will show with some content.

Comment: Why not do it on the server side?

Comment: @Nix Because forummotion does not allow to edit PHP files.

Answer (score 1):

This depends entirely on the framework you use. There are official ways to do it, and there are hacks.

The official way is to use the Framework's API. This API may be available on the front-end for JS, back-end for the server, or even both. Check your framework's documentation for details. If none exists for the front-end but back-end API exists, then you can build code to expose such functionality.

If your platform does not expose an API at all, then you can go with hacks.

One way is to check for the availability of a `userid` on the page. Take for example, the old Friendster which was heavily XSS'ed by widgets and templates. Widgets checked if the user was logged in or not by requesting the profile page via AJAX and checked if a `userid` global variable exists and has a value. Same goes for the Joomla 1.0 and 1.5, although this was on the back-end.

Another way is to AJAX request a known page that should be inaccessible to users that are not logged in. These pages usually return a `403 Forbidden` when the user is not logged in. This status number can be checked using AJAX.